# Communicate from Unity to a FileZilla server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ftp, filezilla

I have create some files from Unity and I want to send them to local server I have created (using FileZilla server). Any idea how can I communicate from the unity project I have to the server I have create with FileZilla? I am trying to implement the suggested code, I got the following error:

> UriFormatException: Invalid URI: Invalid port number
>   System.Uri.Parse (UriKind kind, System.String uriString)
>   System.Uri.ParseUri (UriKind kind)
>   System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString, Boolean dontEscape)
>   System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString)
>   recorgingX.UploadFile (System.String filepath) 
>   recorgingX.OnGUI ()

As m_FtpHost i gave the

> ftp:// + ip + portID

EDIT: I change the slash characters and I no longer get that issue. Now my problem is that while I call `UploadFile (outName);` it doesnt upload it to the server. How can I check what is going on? The proposed code is working fine in c# project however when imported to a UNity project it doesnt do anything. In the filezilla server I am receiving the following:

```
10/2015 17:18:52 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> USER userID
(000025)11/10/2015 17:18:52 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 331 Password required for chrathan
(000025)11/10/2015 17:18:58 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> PASS ***********
(000025)11/10/2015 17:18:58 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 530 Login or password incorrect!
```

Comment: Are you talking about Microsoft Unity or Unity3D?

Comment: What is the different? I havent heard for Microsoft Unity.

Comment: Well Microsoft's Unity is a dependency injection container and Unity3D is a game engine. I suspect you mean the game engine.

Comment: Yes that make sense. I am using 3d engine and I have create a simple gui with buttons where I store some files. Those files I want to send them to ftp server I have created in my PC.

Comment: Take a look at documentation for `System.Net.WebClient` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @snakeplissken it might depend on your platform. A better solution might be to push files via a proxy application rather than directly to an FTP. That way you can use [WWWForm](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html) which is the preferred method in unity to upload things, but it would require a server to accept the data.

Comment: Ok the problem solved it was the matter with slashes. @Rob thanks for the help.

Comment: @snakeplissken great to hear, good job, glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `System.Net.WebClient` class to upload a file to an FTP server.

Here's a theoretical example of how to do that.

```
using System;
using System.Net;

public string m_FtpHost = "ftp://myftpserver.com";
public string m_FtpUsername = "FTP username";
public string m_FtpPassword = "FTP password";

public void UploadFile(string filepath)
{
    // Get an instance of WebClient
    WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
    // parse the ftp host and file into a uri path for the upload
    Uri uri = new Uri(m_FtpHost + new FileInfo(filepath).Name);
    // set the username and password for the FTP server
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(m_FtpUsername, m_FtpPassword);
    // upload the file asynchronously, non-blocking.
    client.UploadFileAsync(uri, "STOR", filepath);
}
```

Documentation for `WebClient` and the other required classes can be found on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx